# Why does fuzzywuzzy process with partial ratio return a different score compared to fuzz partial ratio?

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I assumed that the process.extract method called with the scorer argument set to fuzz.partial_ratio would produce the same output as the fuzz.partial_ratio method. However, that does not seem to be the case:

```
>>>transcript = "July 23rd 2020 in house Sheridan Park alert"
>>>fuzz.partial_ratio(transcript, "Buses")
60
```

Now, with process.extract:

```
>>>process.extract(transcript, ["Buses"], scorer = fuzz.partial_ratio)
[('Buses', 80)]
```

It seems as though fuzz.partial_ratio is matching "Buses" to the "use" in house, but process.extract goes on to disregard the following space and match the "S" in the next word. Is this expected behavior? If so, is there a way to get around it? I want to use the extract (or extractBests) method since my list is about 150 items long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `process.extract` preprocess all strings by:

- lowercasing them
- replacing non alphanumeric characters with whitespace
- stripping whitespaces from begin and end of the strings

This behaviour can be deactivated using the `processor` argument of `process.extract`.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
transcript = "July 23rd 2020 in house Sheridan Park alert"
process.extract(transcript, ["Buses"], processor=None, scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio)
```

will give you `[('Buses', 60)]` as result aswell.

Comment: Actually, just noticed that fuzz.partial_ratio also does not respect white spaces.  
`transcript = "july 23rd 2020 in house sheridan park alert"`  
`fuzz.partial_ratio(transcript, 'buses')`  
also returns 80

Comment: In this case it uses the following alignment: `fuzz.ratio('buses', 'use s')`. FuzzyWuzzy uses the Levenshtein distance with the weights `replace=2, insert=1, remove=1`. So in this case it deletes the whitespace and inserts the b, which is an edit distance of 2. It then normalizes this by using `100 - <edit_distance> * 100 / (len(s1) + len(s2))`. In this case `100 - 200 / 10 = 80`